# Can multi- variate neural networks be inversed?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Imagine I have a neural networks that is a function of the form z= f(x,y). Is there any way to define a neural network that taking z, returns x and y?
if it is possible, how to give two labels to one input and how to define a loss function for it.
I want to use pytorch for it.

I tried to define a network for it but in  defining dataloader stage, I could not figure out how to give two labels to one input and also in defining loss, how to define a loss function. I know that NNs are faunctions and can not return two outputs. But if z is monotone, some times it can help. Is it possible to define such network?

Answer (score 1):

Even if `z` is monotone, you don't known how `x` and `y` contribute to `z=f(x,y)`. In order words, you have two indeterminate state variables which are mapped into an output, therefore for each output, you can have at best two discrete possibilities. Since `x` and `y` are real numbers, this turns out to be indefinite possibilities.

Example: `f` is multiplication

- 3 = 3 x 1
- 8 = 2 x 4
- 48 = 6 x 8
- 49 = 49 x 1

`z` is monotone, and you are now trying to resolve the inverse of a multiplication.

You may achieve what you ask, for particular `f` which basically ignore either `x` or `y`, but that would make the function trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yennefer. But consider the case that x and y are high dimensional and z is a linear combination of them. Is it now possible to define a NNs for it? Because in this case, the inverse of z is almost surely unique.

Comment: I see it a difficult task in general. This link should help you:; https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/17566/can-we-get-the-inverse-of-the-function-that-a-neural-network-represents